# call list not searching all the way through in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, search

I have this code:

```
class Junior_devs:
    entry_list = []
    raise_amount = 1.04
    sum = 0
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, email):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = email
    def apply_raise(self):
        if self in Junior_devs.entry_list:
           self.pay = (int(self.pay) * Junior_devs.raise_amount)
        else:
            self.pay = (int(self.pay) * Senior_devs.raise_amount)
    @classmethod
    def add_employee(cls, string):
        first, last, pay, email = string.split(" ")
        emp = cls(first, last, int(pay), email)
        cls.entry_list.append(emp)
        return emp
    @classmethod
    def sumOfpay(cls):
        sum = 0
        for x in cls.entry_list:
            dicti = x.__dict__
            sum += int(dicti["pay"])
        return sum
    def change_level(self):
        if self in Junior_devs.entry_list:
            Junior_devs.entry_list.remove(self)
            Senior_devs.entry_list.append(self)
        elif self in Senior_devs.entry_list:
            Senior_devs.entry_list.remove(self)
            Junior_devs.entry_list.append(self)
class Senior_devs(Junior_devs):
    entry_list = []
    raise_amount = 1.10


emp1 = Junior_devs.add_employee("imri peretz 20000 imrip27@gmail.com")
emp3 = Junior_devs.add_employee("tray belfort 10000 trey.belfort@gmail.com")
emp2 = Senior_devs.add_employee("Test User 1000 test.user@gmail.com")
emp4 = Senior_devs.add_employee("jordan belfort 2000 jordan.belfort@gmail.com")


print("Juniors: ")
for x in Junior_devs.entry_list:
    print(x.__dict__)
print("Seniors: ")
for x in Senior_devs.entry_list:
    print(x.__dict__)
print("---------------")
for x in Junior_devs.entry_list:
    Junior_devs.change_level(x)
print("Juniors: ")
for x in Junior_devs.entry_list:
    print(x.__dict__)
print("Seniors: ")
for x in Senior_devs.entry_list:
    print(x.__dict__)
```

when i use the change_level function in order to switch an instance from a junior to a senior they all switch but there is always 1 instance that dosent switch.
before using function:

```
Juniors: 
{'first': 'imri', 'last': 'peretz', 'pay': 20000, 'email': 'imrip27@gmail.com'}
{'first': 'tray', 'last': 'belfort', 'pay': 10000, 'email': 'trey.belfort@gmail.com'}
Seniors:
{'first': 'Test', 'last': 'User', 'pay': 1000, 'email': 'test.user@gmail.com'}
{'first': 'jordan', 'last': 'belfort', 'pay': 2000, 'email': 'jordan.belfort@gmail.com'}
```

after using:

```
Juniors:
{'first': 'tray', 'last': 'belfort', 'pay': 10000, 'email': 'trey.belfort@gmail.com'}
Seniors:
{'first': 'Test', 'last': 'User', 'pay': 1000, 'email': 'test.user@gmail.com'}
{'first': 'jordan', 'last': 'belfort', 'pay': 2000, 'email': 'jordan.belfort@gmail.com'}
{'first': 'imri', 'last': 'peretz', 'pay': 20000, 'email': 'imrip27@gmail.com'}
```

the last instance in Juniors should also move to Seniors.
that is what i have trouble with because the way im looping through the entry list of the class should loop through the entire list but i cant find a reason as to why its stopping at the last element. would love some help on this.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: all problem makes `remove()` which you run on list which is iterated. When you remove element from list then next element is moved on its place and later `for`-loop skip this element. You should create function which first append all elements to `Senior` and later it remove all elements. OR  you should work on copy of this list `for x in Junior_devs.entry_list.copy(): ...`

Comment: frankly, I don't like your classes - you use `Senior_devs` inside `Junior_devs` and you have to use `__dict__` to display content - as for me all this is wrong idea. I would rather create normal instances `Junior_devs` and `Senior_devs` and `change_level` should be separated function - or it would have class `Manage` (or `Devs`) which would keep both lists `Junior_devs` and `Senior_devs` and this class would have function `change_level`

Comment: yhea this is my first experience with classes i was just trying to practice inheritance from classes and i chose to display them as dictionaries to lay out the data while debugging

Comment: The class really weird. I know it is your first experience so I am not blaming. The major issue comes from mixing up things that are meant to be different - eg. in your code `Senior_devs` is inherited from `Junior_dev`, but in nature junior dev is not an abstraction from senior dev. These two classes can also mess with each other in the `change_level()` method, which is really strange.

IMO, you have to refactor the class. For example, you could have `Dev` class which is about one single employee regardless of junior/senior status, and each `Dev` has a title of junior/senior.

Comment: yhea i went back to code after and changed it into one class of developers with senior and junior being instances of the class rather then having their own class also helps managing the data of both types of devs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All problem makes `remove()` which you run on iterated list.

When you remove element from list then next element is moved on its place and later `for`-loop skips this element. If you would have more elements then it would skip all "even" elements (second, fourth, 6th, 8th, etc.)

You should first append all elements to `Senior` and later remove all elements from `Junion`.

OR you should work on copy of this list

```py
for x in Junior_devs.entry_list.copy():  # <-- work on copy of list
    Junior_devs.change_level(x)
```